# How to make webview website amp

Tags: android, android-webview, amp-html

```
    WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.loadUrl("http://zzzzzz.com/");
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new com.barometer.app.MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //hide loading image
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //show webview
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }});
```

The code can only call the web with the mobile version. I want to call my web amp. How to?

Comment: Can you give more details of what you've tried?

Comment: I managed to create a webview for the front page. But when I try to enter the amp page (ex. Domain.com/amp) it does not work. What should i do to make it work